# Parameterized Query Reevaluates on Sorting

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have a subform that displays a simple datagrid which allows the user to sort the columns ascending or descending.

The data for that datagrid is provided by a refresh-function, that uses a parameterized query to set the recordsource of the datagrid:

```
Dim query     As DAO.QueryDef
Dim recordSet As DAO.Recordset

Set query = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("DatagridQuery")
query.Parameters("one").Value = combobox_1_value
query.Parameters("two").Value = combobox_2_value
Set recordSet = query.OpenRecordSet
Set Me.subform.From.Recordset = recordSet
```

In this context combobox_1_value and combobox_2_value respectively are provided by two different comboboxes in the parent form.

The problem that now occurs is that the datagrid seemingly reevalutes the underlying query everytime the sort or filter property is set, prompting the user for manual parameter input, instead of fetching the parameter values from the combobox values.

Is there a way that i can bind the values of my comboboxes to the parameters of the query or override the sorting and filtering functions so that i can implement the sorting of the recordset directly in vba?

Answer (score 0):

If you (re)set the recordset, the form will always requeried.

What you could do, is to set the *Filter* property of the form:

```
Me!subform.Form.Filter = "[SomeField] = somevalue"
Me!subform.Form.FilterOn = True
```

For sorting it's the *OrderBy* property:

```
Me!subform.Form.OrderBy = "[SomeField] Asc"
Me!subform.Form.OrderByOn = True
```

Comment: That wouldn't catch the sorting event from datagrid if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: Sorting in the UI doesn't requery. If that is what you see, something else is going on.

Comment: Yeah that is the problem i'm having. When i select a column and order it ascending or descending the underlying query is reevaluated.

Comment: But it shouldn't. Only some other code should cause this. Try building a new simple form and add the datagrid as a subform. No code. This should sort as you request with no requerying.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which apparently results in a longer running time.

I have rewritten the query for the subform to use a global function as a query parameter:

```
Public Function GetComboboxValue()
    GetComboboxValue = Forms!Form1!Combobox.Value
End Function
```

The corresponding query then looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM sampleTbl
WHERE ForeignID = GetComboboxValue()
```

In addition i have set the afterUpdateEvent of the Combobox to requery the subform:

```
Private Sub combobBox_AfterUpdate()
    Me.subform.Requery
End Sub
```

While this works as i want, it seems that the parametrization of the query doesn't work properly anymore. Apparently the query returns all records from the queried table and filters the recordSet only afterwards.

Comment: It would be much simpler to use the `MasterLinkFields` and `ChildLinkFields` properties of the subform control - with the combox value for the master and ForeignID for the child.